# How to pass collection of params to DbClient query in Helidon 4 SE

Tags: java, helidon, helidon-dbclient

I'm trying to implement  database access with Helidon 4 SE, DbClient and PostgresSQL.
Is there any way to pass collection of params to query?
I tried this code:

```java
@Override
    public List<Foo> getFooList(Set<Long> barIds) {
        var query = "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar_id IN (?)";
        return dbClient.execute()
                .createQuery(query)
                .addParam(barIds)
                .execute()
                .stream()
                .map(
                    //parse result
                )
                .toList();
    }
```

But unfortunately it returns the following error:
`Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of java.util.HashSet. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.`
I can't see any methods in query builder that accept collection of params.
Or maybe Helidon DbClient is not suitable for this and I should use another lib?

Answer (score -1):

(I am not an expert in this area of the code.) From a few seconds of looking at [Helidon's copious documentation](https://helidon.io/docs/v4/apidocs/io.helidon.dbclient/io/helidon/dbclient/DbStatement.html) it would seem that the [various documented `params` methods](https://helidon.io/docs/v4/apidocs/io.helidon.dbclient/io/helidon/dbclient/DbStatement.html#params(java.util.List)) might suit your purposes.

Comment: So, could you provide working example?